# Can I do custom events with libuv?

Tags: node.js, libuv

I'm looking to try out libuv, but I need to be able to send events from my networking thread to my main thread. I'm guessing libuv would have custom events to handle this sort of thing but I can't find them.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send them using `uv_async_send`:

- Call `uv_async_init` on the 'main' thread.
- Then call `uv_async_send` from your worker.
- Don't forget `uv_close` back on main.

Reference: https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/threads.html